# How to update the contents of a DynamicItemStart button inside a VS package

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm doing a VS package that has a DynamicItemStart button inside a Menu. I don't have any problem by loading the contents of the Dynamic button when VS starts, but I'm trying to add more commands to its contents after some events like Open a project for example. I add the new commands to this "Place holder" button but I cannot see the Visual Studio UI updated. I have tried the UpdateUI Command:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider(((DTE)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE))) as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);
IVsUIShell uiShell = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell)) as IVsUIShell;
uiShell.UpdateCommandUI(1);
```

I'm calling this code at the BeforeQueryStatus event of the Button, but this doesn't work. Does anyone has achieved anything similar?

Any hints are really appreciated.

Edit 1: Here's the code I use to add the new commands

```
private void InitMRUMenu(ref OleMenuCommandService mcs)
{
  InitializeMRUList();
  if (_connectionsList != null)
  {
    int i = 0; 
    foreach (var conn in _connectionsList)
    {
        var cmdID = new CommandID(GuidList.guidAdvancedVSCTSampleCmdSet, this.baseMRUID + i);
        var mc = new OleMenuCommand(new EventHandler(OnMRUExec), cmdID);
        mruList.Add(conn.DisplayName);
        mc.BeforeQueryStatus += new EventHandler(OnMRUQueryStatus);
        mcs.AddCommand(mc);
        i++;
    }        
  }
}

private void OnMRUQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OleMenuCommand menuCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;
  if (null != menuCommand)
  {
    int MRUItemIndex = menuCommand.CommandID.ID - this.baseMRUID;
    if (MRUItemIndex >= 0 && MRUItemIndex < this.mruList.Count)
    {
      menuCommand.Text = this.mruList[MRUItemIndex] as string;
    }       
  }
}

private void OnMRUExec(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do some actions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some code to the implementation of your [IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget.querystatus.aspx), something like this (in C#):

```
int IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus(ref Guid cmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
{
    if (cmdGroup == yourCommandSet)
    {
        if (prgCmds[0].cmdID >= yourDynamicId && prgCmds[0].cmdID < (yourDynamicId + 16)) // suppose you want a maximum of 16 dynamic items
        {
            int index = (int)prgCmds[0].cmdID - yourDynamicId;

            OLECMDTEXT.OLECMDTEXTF flags = OLECMDTEXT.GetFlags(pCmdText);
            if (flags == OLECMDTEXT.OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_NAME)
            {
                OLECMDTEXT.SetText(pCmdText, "yourText" + index);
            }

            prgCmds[0].cmdf = (uint)(OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED | OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED); // for example
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the associated [IOleCommandTarget.Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget.exec.aspx) must be also modified to correspond (using the same compute index).

The `OLECMDTEXT` is a pretty hacky utility class that can be found on various places on the internet, here it is:

```
/// <devdoc>
/// Helper class for setting the text parameters to OLECMDTEXT structures.
/// </devdoc>
internal static class OLECMDTEXT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Flags for the OLE command text
    /// </summary>
    public enum OLECMDTEXTF
    {
        /// <summary>No flag</summary>
        OLECMDTEXTF_NONE = 0,
        /// <summary>The name of the command is required.</summary>
        OLECMDTEXTF_NAME = 1,
        /// <summary>A description of the status is required.</summary>
        OLECMDTEXTF_STATUS = 2
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the flags of the OLECMDTEXT structure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pCmdTextInt">The structure to read.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the flags.</returns>
    public static OLECMDTEXTF GetFlags(IntPtr pCmdTextInt)
    {
        if (pCmdTextInt == IntPtr.Zero)
            return OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_NONE;

        Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT pCmdText = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pCmdTextInt, typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT));

        if ((pCmdText.cmdtextf & (int)OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_NAME) != 0)
            return OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_NAME;

        if ((pCmdText.cmdtextf & (int)OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_STATUS) != 0)
            return OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_STATUS;

        return OLECMDTEXTF.OLECMDTEXTF_NONE;
    }

    /// <devdoc>
    /// Accessing the text of this structure is very cumbersome.  Instead, you may
    /// use this method to access an integer pointer of the structure.
    /// Passing integer versions of this structure is needed because there is no
    /// way to tell the common language runtime that there is extra data at the end of the structure.
    /// </devdoc>
    public static string GetText(IntPtr pCmdTextInt)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT pCmdText = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pCmdTextInt, typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT));

        // Get the offset to the rgsz param.
        IntPtr offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT), "rgwz");

        // Punt early if there is no text in the structure.
        if (pCmdText.cwActual == 0)
            return String.Empty;

        char[] text = new char[pCmdText.cwActual - 1];
        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)((long)pCmdTextInt + (long)offset), text, 0, text.Length);
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
        s.Append(text);
        return s.ToString();
    }

    /// <include file='doc\NativeMethods.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="OLECMDTEXTF.SetText"]/*' />
    /// <devdoc>
    /// Accessing the text of this structure is very cumbersome.  Instead, you may
    /// use this method to access an integer pointer of the structure.
    /// Passing integer versions of this structure is needed because there is no
    /// way to tell the common language runtime that there is extra data at the end of the structure.
    /// </devdoc>
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the text inside the structure starting from an integer pointer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pCmdTextInt">The integer pointer to the position where to set the text.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text to set.</param>
    public static void SetText(IntPtr pCmdTextInt, string text)
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT pCmdText = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pCmdTextInt, typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT));
        char[] menuText = text.ToCharArray();

        // Get the offset to the rgsz param.  This is where we will stuff our text
        IntPtr offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT), "rgwz");
        IntPtr offsetToCwActual = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.OLECMDTEXT), "cwActual");

        // The max chars we copy is our string, or one less than the buffer size,
        // since we need a null at the end.
        int maxChars = Math.Min((int)pCmdText.cwBuf - 1, menuText.Length);

        Marshal.Copy(menuText, 0, (IntPtr)((long)pCmdTextInt + (long)offset), maxChars);

        // append a null character
        Marshal.WriteInt16((IntPtr)((long)pCmdTextInt + (long)offset + maxChars * 2), 0);

        // write out the length +1 for the null char
        Marshal.WriteInt32((IntPtr)((long)pCmdTextInt + (long)offsetToCwActual), maxChars + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simon: Here's the code that I used to add the new commands to the Dynamic button.

Comment: I'm not using the IOleCommandTarget interface to handle the BeforeQueryStatus or the Exec event, instead I'm using the OleMenuCommand class for the new commands, the BeforeQueryStatus and Exec handlers respectively. I'm not sure how this new Interface fits in my scenario. Could you please explain how this is different or if I should replace the events that I have with the IOleCommandTarget? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gab - In this case OleMenuCommandService implements this interface (you can have a look with a tool such as .NET reflector). Have you tried to create a derived class from OleMenuCommand and override the method 'bool DynamicItemMatch(int cmdId)' and return true?

Comment: No I haven't used it. After checking the documentation I don't think I need to use it. The missing part that I have right now is this: once VS loaded the package and added the dynamic buttons that I have on the intitialize, I can see these commands and everything is fine with that. Then I want to add more command buttons. Let's say after that I open a project. So once the project is open I'm adding one more command on the beforequerystatus event. I can add this command but I cannot see it on the UI. I only see the ones that I added when VS starts. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it finally. I checked the documentation after you mentioned the DynamicItemMatch method. Basically I saw a sample on the msdn so that gave me a better idea; here it is [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx) Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: I have only one missing part. I have the Dynamic button working properly but I want to add more items after the package has been loaded. Like after opening a solution, but the VS UI is not updated. I have opened a new question since this is a different scenario. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032154/how-to-update-visual-studio-ui-on-demand-or-after-an-event-inside-a-vs-package)